# Qt display settings set to grayscale

Tags: c++, qt

How can i change the display settings of QT application that the whole application will be presented in grayscale, one byte per pixel?

I know how to do this using grab,  then convert the color frame to grayscale and then paint it back on PaintEvent, but it is not what i need. 
I'm looking for a way to setup the whole screen as grayscale without need to convert it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with QT, but I'd assume this isn't possible. If you can explain why you need this, you might get a better answer.

Comment: What do you meän by "one byte per pixel"? Where exactly do you want to have this? Windowing system isn't going to be that in any "normal" modern hardware.

Comment: This is not for Windows /Linux.

Comment: This is for custom display hardware,  which supports only frames in 8 bit per pixel. I just want to avoid image processing on each frame.

Comment: @Alex: We'll need quite a bit more information. There's the relatively unknown "Qt for Embedded Linux" which provides its own windowing system (bypassing hyde's remark) but you appear to have an even more unusual situation. The only Qt embedded systems other than Linux are Symbian and Windows CE. You should definitely have mentioned which of the two you are using..

Comment: I'm sorry if i was unclear. My system is Linux running on SBC board,  but the display device is custom made.  I communicate with it by ethernet,  sending frames in grayscale format. I run my application with  - platform offscreen option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is Qt actually supports rendering to a grayscale software rasterizer, that much is obvious looking at `qpaintengine_raster_p.h` and `qpaintengine_raster.cpp`,

The bad news is you will have to implement your own platform plugin, just start with the plugin you are currently using and override it to use a grayscale `QImage` for pixel storage, it won't work with `QPixmap`:

```
case QInternal::Pixmap:
    qWarning("QRasterPaintEngine: unsupported for pixmaps...");
```

Once the platform plugin passes a grayscale `QImage` down the chain, it should be picked up and configure the rasterizer for it.

[More bad news](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpa.html):

> There is no detailed tutorial documentation for writing QPA plugins at
>   this time. However, there are two example plugins shipped with Qt5:
>
> ```
> qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/minimal/
> qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/minimalegl/
> ```

Comment: nice, but not `one byte per pixel` ;)